Pysimplegui to excel
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from shutil import copyfile
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
fromgetting drawing.image import Image


# Adicinar colar para janela
sg.theme('DarkTeal9')

current_dir = Path(__file__).parent if '__file__' in locals() else Path.cwd()
EXCEL_FILE = current_dir / 'Matriz.xlsx'

# Carregar Load the data if the file exists, if not, create a new DataFrame
if EXCEL_FILE.exists():
 df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)
else:
 df = pd.DataFrame()
    
# Criar GUI
layout = [
     [sg.Text('Theme card creator', size=(20,1),font=('Any 15'))],
     [sg.Text('Por favor preencher informações')],
     [sg.Text('Inspeção', size=(15,1)), sg.Combo(['TSIFunction', 'TSIPacking', 'Mass'], key='Inspecao'), sg.Text('Data'), sg.Input(size=(8,1)), sg.CalendarButton(button_text='Escolher')],
     [sg.Text('Defeito', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Defeito')],
     [sg.Text('Linha', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Linha')],
     [sg.Text('SKU', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='SKU')],
     [sg.Text('IMEI', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='IMEI')],
     [sg.Text('Procurar imagem:', size=(15,0)), sg.Input(key='-FILE-'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=((('Imagens', '*.png;*.jpg'),)))],
     [sg.Image(key='-IMAGE-')],
    
   # [sg.Button('Exibir')],

    [sg.Button('Enviar'), sg.Button('Limpar'), sg.Button('Criar'), sg.Exit()]
]

window = sg.Window('Criar Theme card', layout)
7

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None



while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Limpar':
        clear_input()
    elif event == 'Criar':
        new_record = pd.DataFrame(values, index=[0])
        df = pd.concat([df, new_record], ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)  # This will create the file if it doesn't exist
        
        
        
        # Caminho do arquivo original e o destino para a cópia
        caminho_original = 'original.xlsx'
        caminho_destino = 'copia.xlsx'
        quantidade_digitos = 4
        
        # Copiando o arquivo
        copyfile(caminho_original, caminho_destino)
        
        # Renomear arquivo
        novo_nome = values['Defeito']
        codIMEI = values['IMEI'][-quantidade_digitos:]
        
        # Codificar theme card
        novo_caminho = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(caminho_destino), values['Inspecao'] + codIMEI + "_"+ novo_nome + '.xlsx')
        os.rename(caminho_destino, novo_caminho)
        
        
        if event == values["-FILE-"]:
            if filename:
              image_path = values['-FILE-']
              df_inspecao = values['Inspecao']
              wb = load_workbook(novo_caminho)
              ws = wb.active
              ws['E5'] = 'TESTE'
              Image.width = 0.2
              Image.height = 0.2  
              img = Image(image_path)
              ws.add_image(img, 'E5')
              wb.save(novo_caminho)
        
        else:
         sg.popup("No file selected.")

        
      
        workbook = load_workbook(novo_caminho)
        workbook.save(novo_caminho)  
   
    clear_input()
        
window.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Hi guys, I need some help with this code. I’m trying to create a report creator, but for that I need to export data and image from pysimplegui input to a specific cell in excel file when "Criar" button is pressed. When gui has image input it works, but when there is no file gui stucks. I need to creat a code that identifies if image file exists and pops up when it doens't, but in both ways need to create file.
After press "Criar Gui stuks

IMO, you need to add some print statments to find where it stucked. Under the event 'Criar' in the event loop, event == values["-FILE-"] will be always False. Please check above code first, some statements wrong, like fromgetting drawing.image import Image, filename and image_path not defined, sg.popup("No file selected.") bad indent, maybe also more problem somewhere else.
